# How do I set the Tab Order in iText 7?

Tags: pdf-generation, itext7

I'm wondering how to set the Tab Order (for accessibility purposes) in iText 7 via code. In Adobe Acrobat, I can open up Page Properties (see image) and choose the tab order. Now, iText 7 correctly loads and saves existing properties, but I can't figure out a way to actually set the property using code. Does anyone know how to do this?

[image: Page Properties]

Answer (score 2):

Right now there is no convenient API to set tab order on a page in iText7. However, you can always do that on the PDF level using object manipulation.

Assuming you have a `PdfDocument`, you can access any page you want and get a `PdfPage` instance, and then you can set the value of the `/Tabs` key as in the following piece of code:

```
PdfPage page = pdfDoc.getPage(1);
page.put(new PdfName("Tabs"), PdfName.S);
```

Value of `PdfName.S` corresponds to structure order. Other possible values for `PDF 1.7` are `PdfName.C` (column order) and `PdfName.A` (annotations array order).

Please note that now you have to create a `PdfName` instance for `Tabs` manually, but the new `PdfName.Tabs` will be available in `7.0.2`.